# Why do I not have a .pub ssh key?

Tags: ssh

Where is the .pub part to the ct-ssh-14, can there exist a private key on its own, as I did not move any files from .ssh folder?

```
user@user-OptiPlex-760:~/.ssh$ ls -1a
    .
    ..
    config
    ct-ssh-14
    known_hosts
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Having private keys is enough to authenticate. You can generate public key from the private using `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -yf ct-ssh-14
```

It is common practice, when you are offered to download the private key for some service. Downloading two separate files can be troublesome.

Comment: Or, to be a bit more pedantic, the so-called *private key file* contains the full keypair, both the private key and public key components, and you can *extract* the public key using `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: @user4556274 In other words, yes. To be most precise, the public key contains two numbers, which one is shared with the private key and the second can be derived from the other number in the private key (at least for most common RSA).